# How to get iAdBannerView to stretch across full width of Adaptive Layout Storyboard xcode 6

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode6, iad, adaptive-layout

Just wondering how you are supposed to stretch the iAdBannerView across the full width of the Adaptive Layout Storyboard that exists in Xcode 6.

When I try and stretch it to the corners (so I can set auto layout values), it does allow it to be stretched.

Comment: Did you have constraints set? Constraints > frame, in that constraints will override frame change attempts

Answer (score 2):

Your `ADBannerView` will know which device it is on and set its dimensions correctly. You should just let auto layout know where you want the ad to be. For example, if you wanted the `ADBannerView` to be at the bottom of the screen then pin it to the bottom of the view with `Bottom Space to: Bottom Layout Guide` and align it to `Align Center X to: Superview`.

Comment: Also if you want the banner at the bottom you should NOT add Leading and Trailing constraints to the banner or it will add a margin on left/right sides.

Comment: @MarcosReboucas You can add leading/trailing constraints but must set them to, `Leading Space to: Superview Equals: -16.0` and `Trailing Space to: Superview Equals: -16.0`. Its just not absolutely necessary.

Comment: That's right I mean it will add margins if you add these unnecessary constraints with zero values.