# How to change iAd Banner View Size for iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, iad

I have a SpriteKit game with an iAd Banner in my Main.storyboard file and I've implemented constraints using auto layout to fit the banner to the bottom of the screen. The app is supposed to be a universal app, but when the app is run on the iPad, the banner does not seem to change to the iPad-sized banner, and doesn't fit the whole width of the screen. How do I get the banner to be one size on the iPad and and different size on the iPhone by using only one .storyboard file?

Comment: This answer may be what you're looking for. I haven't tested it while using SpriteKit though. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28596752/2108547

Comment: Thanks, that worked! For some reason I didn't try the horizontal center in container, but just did constraints to each side of the view. If you post again as an answer, I'll choose it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ADBannerView` will know which device it is on and set the dimensions of the `ADBannerView` correctly. You should just let auto layout know where you want the ad to be. For example, if you wanted the `ADBannerView` to be at the bottom of the screen then pin it to the bottom of the screen with `Bottom Space to: Bottom Layout Guide` and align it to `Align Center X to: Superview`.

Comment: Good answer, Daniel. I tried using the constraints to fit it to the two sides of the screen, but when I removed them, it worked out fine. Strange that it does that.